# Static assertions that a type has no data members

Tags: c++, c++11, static-assert

My type currently has no instance data members. I want to ensure that none are accidentally added in the future.

Can I do this with a `static_assert` and `type_traits` somehow? The best I came up with was asserting the size of the type, but as it must also be abstract this [won't work](http://ideone.com/xrROtA), or at least not in a portable fashion.

I'm happy to allow static data members.

Comment: No, I don't think so. Why do you want this? Seems like a smell.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, at the risk of derailing the question: the use case is creating pure-virtual base classes for type-erasure on a template class hierarchy. Essentially I want to ensure the type is 'safe' as a secondary base class, as would be the case for a C# or Java interface.

Comment: Shame C++ doesn't have "interfaces" then.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, given you have some more insight into my situation, can you point me at any other resources or approaches which may be useful?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing comes to mind.

Comment: Is there something in the new revisions of the standard that can help with this? It's an interesting problem indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the size of the type is a fine idea.  You can simply make a dummy class which is abstract, and then:

```
static_assert(sizeof(T) == sizeof(Dummy), "oops");
```

That is, check that the size of the target class is the same as the size of a class which is known to have no data members.

Comment: Note the size may differ in case of `virtual` functions and/or destructors. Not to mention this is probably implementation defined if this works at all.

Comment: @rubenvb: I specifically said that the dummy class would be abstract (i.e. have virtual functions), and the OP said the same was true of the target class.  I challenge you to find an implementation where it doesn't work.  :)

Comment: Yes, the class in question will always be abstract in my case (I already assert `is_abstract<T>::value`).

Comment: This cannot seriously be reliable?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: _"I challenge you to find an implementation where it doesn't work."_ Ugh, really? This line of reasoning causes space rockets to explode. Instead of saying "this is fine because I only know of implementations X, Y, Z and it works in all three", say "this is fine because it is guaranteed to be so in _all implementations deemed to be compliant to the international standard_". Then, when that rocket explodes, it's not your fault.

Comment: This is not guaranteed to work by the standard but I don't know of an implementation where it would fail.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit why of course it is your fault: you have used C++ in a rocket.

Comment: @n.m. The principle applies to _all_ fields of engineering and [almost] all languages within our tiny corner of it.

Comment: Of course, if it's the best that can be done, then using this with a great bit warning comment splattered around it, and ideally some #ifdefs so that only known implementations may build the code, would probably suffice.

Comment: *"I challenge you to find an implementation where it doesn't work."* Challenge accepted :) Use ARM64 gcc 13.2 with the `-fstruct-pack=8` flag. `struct Dummy {
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

struct T {
    virtual void f() = 0;
    bool a;
};

static_assert(alignof(T) == sizeof(Dummy), "oops");`

Compiles successfully. 
godbolt link:
https://godbolt.org/z/n4E6eee9e